# How do i fix my navbar that won't go responsive properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

when i was trying to make a responsive navbar i ran into this width problem

so here's the HTML code

```css
body{
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    .nav{
        background-color: lightgreen;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .footer{
        background-color: #333;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i it all worked fine until i go to the "developer tools" and viewed it on android, even though i make width 100% it still didn't reach the other end when i make it smaller
[image]

Comment: You'd need to remove the padding from your footer and put it on the child elements on instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is the footer. By default padding is added to the element's overall width and height. So when you give footer a width of 100% with 20px padding the width actually becomes 100%+20px+20px.

This can be easily overcome by adding `box-sizing:border-box` to your footer class. Or many people just set it to every element like `*{box-sizing:border-box}` so you won't have that problem again.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

> border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in
> the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set
> an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any
> border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb
> that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size
> elements.

```css
body{
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    .nav{
        background-color: lightgreen;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .footer{
        background-color: #333;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing:border-box
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```